# Range selection for graph plotting in vba

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I'm trying to automate the process of generating graphs using a vba macro. The following code gives me the error Object variable or With block variable not set. I've shown my code below it breaks on the xrange line. I would appreciate any help people may have.

```
' Chart update
Dim xrange As Range, yrange As Range
Dim co As Object
Left = 1500: Top = 250: Width = 280: Height = 210

'Draw the Charts
' Set range
xrange = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(17, 3))
yrange = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(17, 4))
'
Set co = Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects.Add(Left, Top, Width, Height)
co.Name = "Chart1"
co.Chart.ChartWizard Source:=yrange, _
Gallery:=xlXYScatterSmooth, PlotBy:=xlColumns, Format:=1, _
CategoryLabels:=0, SeriesLabels:=0, HasLegend:=False, Title:="Chart Title", _
CategoryTitle:=xlabel, ValueTitle:=ylabel
co.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = xrange
```

Comment: You need to write : with NameOfGraph
And after you'll use .xrange , etc

Comment: Thanks Alex it worked when I used ranges after the name of graph. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see couple of errors.

1. `Left`, `Width` are reserved words. You shouldn't be using them as a variable. You can use `Lft` and `Wdt` in place of them.
2. Your Cells object are not fully qualified. I would recommend using objects instead of `ActiveSheet`.

For example (Notice the DOT before Cells)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim xrange As Range, yrange As Range
    Dim co As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    lft = 1500: Top = 250: wdt = 280: Height = 210

    With ws
        xrange = .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(17, 3))
        yrange = .Range(.Cells(2, 4), .Cells(17, 4))

        '
        '~~> Rest of the code
        '
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Top and Height are also reserved words.